# Dedupe python list based on multiple criteria

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list:
    mylist = [('Item A','CA','10'),('Item B','CT','12'),('Item A','CA','14'),('Item A','NH','10')]

I would like to remove duplicates based on column 1 and 2. So my desired output would be:

```
[('Item A','CA','10'),('Item B','CT','12'),('Item A','NH','10')]
```

I'm not really sure how to go about this, so I haven't posted any code, but am just looking for some help :)

Answer (score 1):

Use a dict.  The other answer is good. For variety, here's a single expression that will give you the uniq'd list (though the order of elements is not preserved).

```
{ tuple(item[0:2]):item for item in mylist[::-1] }.values()
```

This creates a dict from the elements of mylist using elements 0 and 1 as the key (implicitly removing duplicates). Because mylist is iterated in reverse order, the last element with a duplicate key (elements 0 and 1) will remain in the dict.

Answer (score 0):

Dict keys can be of any hashable type.  Create a dict with the first two columns of each item as the key, and only add to `unique` if those columns haven't been seen before.

```
unique = {}
for item in mylist:
    if item[0:2] not in unique:
        unique[item[0:2]] = item
print unique.values()
```

Comment: You can't use lists as keys. tuples are fine though. Fortunately the source list contains tuples :)